# Science fiction movie: electrical power kills astronauts on spaceship and ground station

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know the name of a movie in which the following happens, starting from the beginning:

- some astronauts are in a spaceship and one of them is playing chess online with one of his friend on the earth
- then suddenly some electrical power comes and strikes the ship and kills all, and it's also beamed to the staion on the ground  and there also it kills all, and then it works on power preparing minibots
- someone shuts down the power to turn off the deadly thing
- but then later some visitor comes and turns on the power and then some survivor warns them to shut it down else all are dead
- meanwhile, some of the visitors explore the place when they find the mini bots and interrupt them, and in return it attacks them
- and later one by one they are being killed, then they interact with the killer program or whatever it is by computer - which replies that a species is deteriorating the environment and so it is killing them

I would like to watch this movie again. Does anyone know its name?

Comment: When did you watch this film? How old was it? What language was it in? Any little detail can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could be [Virus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120458/) from 1999.

It starts off with a Russian space station communicating with a research ship (i.e. regular marine ship). There is a chess game in progress between an astronaut (or cosmonaut) and a scientist in the ship.

An alien intelligence in the form of electricity destroys the space station and beams itself down to the ship.

The visitors are the crew of a ship which has lost its cargo in a storm. They find the desolate research ship and see it as a chance to recover their costs via salvage rights.

The rest is a battle against machines made from canabalised parts. Some part human. It all gets a bit silly.

Actually the description in the question is probably as good as what I can remember of this film (and I saw it less than a year ago). The clincher is probably the chess game which you can see at about 2m15s into [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02L38m3GoDo).

Comment: Bro thats exactly the film and thank you so much . :)

Comment: @VikashMeena If you found Fruitbat's answer useful, you should [accept it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the greyed-out checkmark icon next to it.